# What is the purpose of the pond in Desert Cantos?

Tags: terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In *The Sarah Connor Chronicles*, episode "Desert Cantos" ([wikia link](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_215:_Desert_Cantos)), a drone is seen leaving the pool. My question is simply what is really going on with this pool?

I do not recall seeing any real explanation for the pond itself other than some dead animals, plus if memory serves other episodes may have also shown activity around this too; I do recall a scene with it bubbling at least.

Comment: The bubbling I reference might of been a different episode. I have not seen it for quite a while. But there is something a bit fishy ( no pun intended ) about this pond in general.